# power query has problem with non-English characters

Tags: excel

When I try to write formula in power query:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE0VS.png)

non-English characters looks like this. I've tried this on another computer but works just fine. I use windows 11 and Microsoft Office 2021, I also have same problem with Power BI Desktop. If someone knows how to fix this, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the formatting of your excel file:
This can be done when pressing Save As. Here you should have an option to save  the file as UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded. Then try again with the UTF encoded file.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I wasn't able to find that option. what I found was tools>web options>Encoding, but there was only UTF-8. and it didn't work.

Comment: looks like there was problem with windows, I reinstall windows and everything is working fine.